# Is it possible to use declared variables in a check in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a check constraint on a table in postgres based on some ids in another table. I know you can't do it directly with a select in the check however I thought it would be possible to get the ids into a variable and use them in the check but that doesn't seem to work either. This is what I have:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  assigned uuid := (select "WorkOrderStatusCodeId" from "WorkOrdersV2"."WorkOrderStatusCodes" where "Code" = 'A');
  onHold uuid := (select "WorkOrderStatusCodeId" from "WorkOrdersV2"."WorkOrderStatusCodes" where "Code" = 'O');
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE "WorkOrdersV2"."WorkOrders" ADD CHECK (("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" not in (assigned, onHold) and "DisplayOrder" is null) or ("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" in (assigned, onHold) and "DisplayOrder" is not null));
END $$;
```

It's giving me an error: `ERROR: column "assigned" does not exist`

Is there any way to do this with a check constraint or do I need to use a trigger?

Comment: You must use dinamic sql i.e.: execute 'ALTER TABLE "WorkOrdersV2"."WorkOrders" ADD CHECK (("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" not in (' || assigned || ',' || onHold || ') and "DisplayOrder" is null) or ("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" in (' ||assigned || ', ' || onHold || ') and "DisplayOrder" is not null));'

Comment: @AbdelP. You're correct but you are missing the single quotes around assigned and onHold. Make this an answer and add quotes and I will mark it as the answer

Comment: If you tried, but it will not take the values of the variables with the single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use dynamic SQL:

```
execute 'ALTER TABLE "WorkOrdersV2"."WorkOrders" ADD CHECK (("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" not in (''' || assigned || ''',''' || onHold || ''') and "DisplayOrder" is null) or ("WorkOrderStatusCodeId" in (''' ||assigned || ''', ''' || onHold || ''') and "DisplayOrder" is not null));'
```